# How to use buildThemes task to update css

Tags: cuba-platform

I'm calling

```
gradlew buildThemes
```

from the project directory to update an extended theme, after putting new css rules in halo-ext.scss.
What I'm supposed to do next? Refreshing the web page or closing and reopening it doesn't work, **I get the new rules applied only after restarting the app from Cuba Studio**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle **buildThemes** task does not copy CSS result files to a local tomcat instance. Use separate **deployThemes** task along with Ctrl-F5 short-cut (empty cache) in your browser.